# Kubernetes way to Load balance/Failover external MariaDB PXC cluster nodes

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb

I am trying to setup access to an external MySQL database that is setup using MariaDB PXC three node cluster.

Let say my external database nodes has these IP addresses

```
172.16.10.100
172.16.10.101
172.16.10.102
```

In case one of those nodes goes down, I want Kubernetes to automatically route traffic to only available two nodes.

If I create a simple Service and Endpoints in kubernetes (showing below), does it automatically do a failover?

```yaml
#
# Service
#
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mariadb-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  sessionAffinity: None
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3306
---
#
# Endpoints
#
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mariadb-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 172.16.10.100
      - ip: 172.16.10.101
      - ip: 172.16.10.102
    ports:
      - port: 3306
        protocol: TCP
```

Comment: what cloud provider are you using?

Comment: @Bazhikov No cloud providers, this is a on premises kubernetes cluster

Comment: sorry for late reply. What do you mean by external database, is it outside of the clusters?

Comment: Yes databases run outside of Kubernetes cluster, database setup in a 3 node multi master cluster so in case one node fails, client services can switch to other available nodes to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please note this:

> **Kubernetes does not offer** an implementation of network load balancers (Services of type LoadBalancer) for bare-metal clusters. The implementations of network load balancers that Kubernetes does ship with are all glue code that calls out to various IaaS platforms (GCP, AWS, Azure…). If you’re not running on a supported IaaS platform (GCP, AWS, Azure…), LoadBalancers will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely when created.

I found the option to have LoadBalancer with on premises Kubernetes cluster - that is [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/)

> **MetalLB** aims to redress this imbalance by offering a network **load balancer** implementation that integrates with standard network equipment, so that external services **on bare-metal clusters** also “just work” as much as possible.

See the [requirements](https://metallb.universe.tf/#requirements) and the [installation options](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/) you prefer.

[MetalLB respects the spec.loadBalancerIP parameter](https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/#requesting-specific-ips), so if you want your service to be set up with a specific address, you can request it by setting that parameter. MetalLB also supports requesting a specific address pool, if you want a certain kind of address but don’t care which one exactly. To request assignment from a specific pool, add the metallb.universe.tf/address-pool annotation to your service, with the name of the address pool as the annotation value. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: production-public-ips
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

And for `address-pool annotation` you can define it something like:

```
address-pools:
  name: production-public-ips
  protocol: TCP
  addresses:
  - ip: 172.16.10.100
  - ip: 172.16.10.101
  - ip: 172.16.10.102
  ports:
  - port: 3306
```

Find full example usage [here](https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/example/).

However, there is no health check implemented, that is main option for you.

There is an ideal [issue example on GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77738) and [this thread](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/6492#issuecomment-599699681) explaining on why health check is not implemented for Kubernetes CRDs.

If we jump into Kubernetes concepts, this use case is not doable and you can seek for some custom endpoint controller:

> readinessProbe: Indicates whether the container is ready to respond to requests. If the readiness probe fails, the endpoints controller removes the Pod's IP address from the endpoints of all Services that match the Pod. The default state of readiness before the initial delay is Failure. If a Container does not provide a readiness probe, the default state is Success.

Please find more information in [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes)